# naver pinpoint doesn't show background thread?

Tags: java, apm

In APM pinpoint, I can see all http calls threads for Java sample application on "**Real time active thread chart**". But i cannot find out any background running thread which internal threads. Is there any way to display those threads in chart?

Answer (score 2):

Very late reply, but just in case, could you try adding your background service to 
profiler.entrypoint in pinpoint.config

e.g. `profiler.entrypoint=com.example.background.ClassName.methodName`